# Are there any other trains or platforms in King's Cross going to the wizard world?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry takes the Hogwarts Express to get to school all the six years when he's attending Hogwarts (with the exception of his second year, of course; but he *was* trying to get on it) and boards the train from platform 9¾.

Are there any wizarding trains other than the Hogwarts Express, and are there any platforms other than 9 ¾ that witches and wizards can take from King's Cross to their world?

Comment: See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15764/where-do-the-other-platforms-lead and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/67914/46027

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## None in the books, but on Pottermore, JKR said there are others.

In the books, as well as in the movies, the only wizarding train platform shown was Platform Nine and Three Quarters. However, in a writing on Pottermore, JKR says that she’d thought there would be other platforms hidden between the Muggle ones.

> J.K. Rowling’s thoughts
>
> In choosing the number of the concealed platform that would take young witches and wizards to boarding school, I decided that it would have to be a number between those of the Muggle platforms – therefore, it was clearly a fraction. This raised the interesting question of how many other fractional platforms lay between the whole-numbered platforms at King’s Cross, and I concluded that were probably quite a few. Although these are never mentioned in the book, I like to think that it is possible to take a version of the Orient Express off to wizard-only villages in continental Europe (try platform seven and a half), and that other platforms may be opened on an as-required-basis, for instance for large, one-off events such as Celestina Warbeck concerts (see your ticket for details). 
> <sub><sup>*[Platform Nine and Three-Quarters (Pottermore)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/platform-nine-and-three-quarters)*</sup></sub>